# Are buffers generally faster to work with than streams?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, imagemagick, buffer

I've tried a couple of Imagemagick wrapper libraries and some S3 libraries. I'm having trouble choosing the best concept due to big performance differences.

I have settled with the node library "gm", which is a joy to work with and very well documented.

As for S3 I have tried both Amazon's own AWS library as well as "S3-Streams"

---

**Edit:** I just discovered that the AWS library can handle streams. I suppose this is a new function s3.upload (or have I just missed it?). Anyway, I ditched *s3-streams* which makes use of s3uploadPart which is much more complicated. **After switching library streaming is equal to uploading buffers in my test case.**

---

My testcase is to split a 2MB jpg file into approx 30 512px tiles and send each of the tiles to S3. Imagemagick has a really fast automatic way of generating tiles via the crop command. Unfortunately I have not found any node library that can catch the multi file output from the autogenerated tiles. Instead I have to generate tiles in a loop by call the crop command individually for each tile.

**I'll present the total timings before the details:**

**A**: 85 seconds  (s3-streams)

**A**: 34 seconds  (aws.s3.upload)  (EDIT)

**B**: 35 seconds  (buffers)

**C**: 25 seconds  (buffers in parallell)

Clearly buffers are faster to work with than streams in this case. I don't know if *gm* or *s3-streams* has a bad implementation of streams or if I should have tweaked something. For now I'll go with solution B. C is even faster, but eats more memory.

I'm running this on a low end Digital Ocean Ubuntu machine. This is what I have tried:

**A. Generate tiles and stream them one by one**

- I have an array prepared with crop information and s3Key for each tile to generate
- The array is looped with "async.eachLimit(1)". I have not succeeded in generating more than one tile at once, hence limit(1).
- As the tiles are generated, they are directly streamed to S3

Pseudo code:

```
async.eachLimit(tiles, 1, function(tile, callback) {
    gm(originalFileBuffer)
    .crop(tile.width, tile.height, tile.x, tile.y)
    .stream()
    .pipe(s3Stream({Key: tile.key, Bucket: tile.bucket}))  //using "s3-streams" package
    .on('finish', callback)
});
```

**B. Generate tiles to buffers and upload each buffer directly with AWS-package**

- As the tiles are generated to buffers, they are directly uploaded to S3

Pseudo code:

```
async.eachLimit(tiles, 1, function(tile, callback) {
    gm(originalFileBuffer)
    .crop(tile.width, tile.height, tile.x, tile.y)
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
      s3.upload(..
        callback()
      )        
    })
});
```

**C. Same as B, but store all buffers in the tile array for later upload in parallell**

Pseudo code:

```
async.eachLimit(tiles, 1, function(tile, callback) {
    gm(originalFileBuffer)
    .crop(tile.width, tile.height, tile.x, tile.y)
    .toBufer(function(err, buffer) {
      tile.buffer = buffer;
      callback()
    })
});
```

..this next step is done after finalizing the first each-loop. I don't seem to gain speed by pushing limit to more than 10.

```
async.eachLimit(tiles, 10, function(tile, callback) {
  s3.upload(tile.buffer..
    callback()
  )        
});
```

---

**Edit:** Some more background as per Mark's request
I originally left out the details in the hope that I would get a clear answer about buffer vs stream.

The goal is to serve our app with images in a responsive way via a node/Express API. Backend db is Postgres. Bulk storage is S3.

Incoming files are mostly photos, floor plan drawings and pdf document. The photos needs to be stored in several sizes so I can serve them to the app in a responsive way: thumbnail, low-res, mid-res and original resolution.

Floor plans has to be tiles so I can load them incrementally (scrolling tiles) in the app. A full resolution A1 drawing can be about 50 MPixels.

Files uploaded to S2 spans from 50kB (tiles) to 10MB (floor plans).

The files comes from various directions, but always as streams:

- Form posts via web or some other API (SendGrid)
- Uploads from the app
- Downloaded stream from S3 when uploaded files needs more processing

I'm not keen on having the files temporarily on local disk, hence only buffer vs stream. If I could use the disk I'd use IM's own tile function for really speedy tiling.

Why not local disk?

- Images are encrypted before uploading to S3. I don't want unencrypted files to linger in a temp directory.
- There is always the issue of cleaning up temp files, with possible orphan files after unintended crashes etc.

Comment: You have kind of dived straight into the details without giving any overview of what you are trying to achieve... Why are you sending images? Where from? Are they coming back? What dimensions are they? Are they JPEG or PNG or other? Are you trying to send as many images per second to AWS/S3 as possible? Or to parallelise some processing? Or re-assemble something? Why must you tile them?

Comment: I have added some background in the original post. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: As a side-node. I can run gm.crop() in parallel (eachLimit(10)) under OSX. But the same code crashes on Ubuntu. On OSX it takes 6 seconds instead of 25 seconds when I run it in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more tinkering I feel obliged to answer my own question.

Originally I used the npm package *s3-streams* for streaming to S3. This package uses aws.s3.uploadPart.

Now I found out that the aws package has a neat function aws.s3.upload which takes a buffer or a stream.

After switching to AWS own streaming function there is no time difference between buffer/stream-upload.

I might have used s3-streams in the wrong way. But I also discovered a possible bug in this library (regaring files > 10MB). I posted an issue, but haven't got any answer. My guessing is that the library has been abandoned since the *s3.upload* function appeared.

So, the answer to my own question:

**There might be differences between buffers/streams, but in my test case they are equal, which makes this a non issue for now.**

Here is the new "save"-part in the each loop:

```
    let fileStream = gm(originalFileBuffer)
      .crop(tile.width, tile.height, tile.x, tile.y)
      .stream();
    let params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: tile.s3Key, Body: fileStream};
    let s3options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};

    s3.upload(params, s3options, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
      callback()
    });
```

Thank you for reading.